# How do I apply nvprof to Kinetica?

Tags: nvprof, kinetica

Can someone pls gimme a hint on how to apply nvprof to Kinetica ?

1) I see the name of processes of Kinetica which sits upon GPUs is gpudb_cluster_cuda, and its parent process is gpudb_host_manager.   I find gpudb_host_manager is started by /etc/rc.d/init.d/gpudb_host_manager.

2) Thus I modified it as below.   This should work - even for its child processes.  But it doesn't.  No profiling data was produced for gpudb_cluster_cuda.

```
# vi /etc/rc.d/init.d/gpudb_host_manager
...
#        $START_PROG"$GPUDB_EXE start-host-manager 2>&1 | tee -a ${STARTUP_LOG}; ( exit \${PIPESTATUS[0]} )"
        $START_PROG"/usr/local/cuda-9.2/bin/nvprof --log-file /tmp/nvprof/%p.txt --export-profile /tmp/nvprof/%p.nvvp --print-gpu-trace --profile-child-processes $GPUDB_EXE start-host-manager 2>&1 | tee -a ${STARTUP_LOG}; ( exit \${PIPESTATUS[0]} )"
...
```

I applied nvprof to /etc/rc.d/init.d/gpudb, and it produces some traces but it does not use GPUs at all.

```
# vi /etc/rc.d/init.d/gpudb
...
#        $START_PROG"$GPUDB_EXE start 2>&1 | tee -a ${STARTUP_LOG}; ( exit \${PIPESTATUS[0]} )"
       $START_PROG"/usr/local/cuda-9.2/bin/nvprof --log-file /tmp/nvprof/%p.txt --export-profile /tmp/nvprof/%p.nvvp --print-gpu-trace --profile-child-processes $GPUDB_EXE start 2>&1 | tee -a ${STARTUP_LOG}; ( exit \${PIPESTATUS[0]} )"
...
```

Of course, I stopped and restarted these.  Any comment would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I found that nvprof can be applied by editing /opt/gpudb/core/bin/gpudb as below.

```
[root@localhost ~]# vi /opt/gpudb/core/bin/gpudb
...
#    nohup $HOST_MANAGER_CMD >> $HOST_MANAGER_LOG_FILENAME 2>&1 &
    nohup /usr/local/cuda-9.2/bin/nvprof --log-file /tmp/nvprof/%p.txt --export-profile /tmp/nvprof/%p.nvvp --print-gpu-trace --profile-child-processes $HOST_MANAGER_CMD >> $HOST_MANAGER_LOG_FILENAME 2>&1 &
...
```